# ElectronJS for Linux touch mobile operating systems?

Tags: linux, electron, mobile-development, sailfish-os, ubuntu-touch

ElectronJS is cross-platform framework to create desktop apps for Mac, Windows and Linux.

But if I make an app using responsive web design for mobile views, will the distribution for Linux work for Ubuntu Touch, Sailfish OS, Mobian, and many other Linux mobile touch operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

In Sailfish OS it would not work, because no Electron in SailfishOS, if you want, you can try build it by your self (Electron should support Wayland platform, but in SailfishOS we have old Waland protocol version, in Ubuntu Touch, on Mir, it has more chance to make electorn work, dont know about mobian nothing)