# Will Ubuntu Desktop apps run on Ubuntu Touch OS and devices using Electron?

Tags: ubuntu, electron, mobile-development, ubuntu-touch

I want to create Ubuntu Touch mobile apps using the latest technologies from HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript (especially Angular or VueJS). The only cross-platform hybrid framework that has a lot of community and support is ElectronJS.

But ElectronJS is for Desktop (for MacOS, Windows, and Linux). **If I create a distribution for Linux/Ubuntu Desktop using ElectronJS, will this app be fully compatible on Ubuntu Touch Mobile OS?**

Please take into account that the UI will be mobile responsive so that screen sizes for Phone and Tablet sizes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElectronJS for Linux touch mobile operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65889861/electronjs-for-linux-touch-mobile-operating-systems)